# Discussing if we should borrow a "Closing question as Off-Topic reason"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

On Robotics.SE they have the following option in the **Close --> Off-Topic** list.

> **Life Questions** are off-topic. Questions about choosing how to spend your time (what book to read, which class to take, what robotics project to construct, what career to pursue, etc.) may be about difficult decisions, and they are often important, but they are too specific to your own situation and are unlikely to help future visitors to the site. They would be better off asked in Robotics Chat.

The quote says it all, what type of regular questions brought this option alive.

I think recently we had a question in this category and as we did not discuss such topic so far I though that we should now.

As IoT is quite a popular buzzword there could be questions (very very broadly speaking here) like:

"I want to do some IoT, where should I start".

Currently it does not seem to be a serious problem and maybe we do not need this closing reason at all, but we can talk about it in advance.

Maybe there are three ways:

1. We won't have some much of these questions, those few simply can be closed as **"primarily opinion-based"**. Maybe comment these words if they really apply.
2. Include this text only in the Help Center like [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
3. Add it as a close reason.
4. +1 It is completely unnecessary.

Comment: For context: we (the moderators) can add up to three site-specific close reasons, and any close reasons that can be proven to be useful for a large amount of questions will be considered.

Comment: For your specific suggestion, I'm unsure exactly how many questions would require this reason as opposed to just closing as 'primarily opinion based' or 'too broad'. I can see the appeal of more information in the close reason, although a comment might be sufficient. Perhaps 'wait and see' would be wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's too early to add is as a close reason. We've got only three and we should make them count. So for the time being let's go with your option one and add it to the help center if we get a few more applicable questions.

For the time being can use comments and too broad / primarily opinion based to handle these questions—if they keep popping up.